# grub-reboot and grub-set-default don't work properly

Tags: ubuntu, partition, grub2

I have a fresh installed Ubuntu (Server) 18.04.
I added a custom menu entry `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`:

```
menuentry "Backup" {
set root=(hd0,3)
linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3 ro quiet splash
initrd /initrd.img
}
```

Until now anything works fine, the custom menu entry is visible and I can boot from it.
Now I tried to set the default via `grub-set-default 3` and/or set the default temporary `grub-reboot 3`.
Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes not.

As example currently the file `/boot/grub/default` contains `0` and the file `/boot/grub/grubenv` contains `saved_entry=0`.

My grub config(`/etc/default/grub`) looks like this

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pci=nomsi"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I've also run the `update-grub` command.

Any ideas or suggestions how I can fix it?